# prove that there exists $g(x)\neq 0$ so that $f(x)g(x)$ has only nonnegative coefficients iff none of the roots of f(x) are positive

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, induction

> Prove (or disprove) that for a given nonzero real polynomial $f(x)$ there exists a nonzero real polynomial $g(x)$ for which all the coefficients of $f(x)g(x)$ are nonnegative (respectively positive) iff none of the roots of f(x) are positive (respectively nonnegative).

We can factorize any polynomial uniquely up to ordering as a product of irreducibles in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, the set of polynomials with real coefficients.
Note that we can always choose $g(x)$ to be a monic polynomial provided the leading coefficient of $f(x)$ is positive. I'm not sure about how to prove the general case but some examples include the case when $f(x)=x^6-x^4+2x^3-x^2+1$ or $f(x)=x^2-x+1$. In the first case, we can take $g(x) = x^3+2x^2+2x+1$ so that $f(x)g(x)$ only has positive coefficients. In the second case, we can take $g(x) = x+1.$ We'll first consider making all the coefficients of $f(x)g(x)$ nonnegative in special cases.  Note that $f(x) = x-1$ has a positive root, and it is indeed impossible to find a polynomial $g(x)$ so that $f(x)g(x)$ has only nonnegative coefficients; if $g(x)$ is such a polynomial it must be nonconstant and if $g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n g_i x^i$ then $f(x)g(x) = g_n x^{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^n x^i (g_{i-1} - g_i) - g_0$. In particular we need to have $g_0 \leq 0$ and $g_{i-1}\ge g_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. So $g_{n-1} \ge g_n \ge 0$ and $g_{n-2}\ge g_{n-1}\ge 0$ imply (by induction) that $g_0\ge 0$ so $g_0 = 0$. But then $g(x)$ must be the zero polynomial (all the inequalities $g_{n-1}\ge g_n\ge 0$ etc. must hold with equality), a contradiction.

I think it might be useful to prove this by induction on the degree of $f(x)$. Note that if none of the roots of $f(x)$ are positive, then $f(x)$ must have the same sign on the positive real numbers by the IVT.

Comment: Doesn't your observation that a non-zero polynomial with non-negative coefficients is positive for $x\gt 0$ do most of the work you need? A positive root of $f(x)$ can't disappear when you multiply it by $g(x)$. You then have to deal with quadratic factors which have no real roots.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is actually false. Try the polynomial $f(x)=3x^2-3x+1$. I can prove there is no $g(x)$ of degree $1$ or $2$. Unfortunately I just brute forced it though and can't see how to extend the proof to higher dimensions.