# prove that P is linear

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials

> Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial so that for any integer $n, P(x)=n$ has a rational solution. Show all the coefficients of $P(x)$ are rational. Furthermore, show that $P(x)$ is linear.

To see why all the coefficients of $P$ are rational, choose a rational $x_k\in\mathbb{Q}$ so that $P(x_k)=k$ for $0\leq k\leq n,$ where $n=\deg P.$ Then by Lagrange interpolation, $P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n k \prod_{j\neq k} \dfrac{x-x_j}{x_k-x_j}$. Then $P(x)$ is a sum of polynomials all of whose coefficients are rational, so $P(x)$ has the same property.

> But how do I show $P$ is linear? I know this occurs iff $P$ has a bounded derivative.

Comment: Here is the basic idea: if $P(x)$ were, say, $x^k, k \ge 2$, then it is not possible for $x^k = n$ to always have a rational solution, since $\sqrt[k]{n}$ is not rational most of the time. Try to generalize this argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't really need $n$ to run all over $\mathbb{Z}$; restricting to $\mathbb{N}$ is enough to solve your problem.

As you have already proved, $P\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. Then $\exists~M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $Q=MP\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thus $Q(x)=Mn$ has a rational root, say $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now by [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) , theorem, we know that $q_n\mid D$, where $D$ is the leading coefficient of $Q$. Thus, we must have $|q_n|\le D, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence we must have $|\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}-\frac{p_n}{q_n}|\ge  \frac{1}{D}$. But recall that $Q(\frac{p_n}{q_n})=Mn$. Thus by LMVT,
$$Q\left(\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}\right)-Q\left(\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right)=M$$
$$\implies |M|\ge \frac{|Q'(r_n)|}{|D|}  \qquad(*)$$
where $r_n$ is between $\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}$ and $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$. Also observe
$\{\frac{p_n}{q_n}\}_{n\ge 1}$ is unbounded(why?), hence $r_n$ is also unbounded. Now if $Q$ were not a linear polynomial, $Q'(r_n)$ would be unbounded, contradicting $(*)$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you take a look at [this polynomial problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549685/prove-that-there-exists-gx-neq-0-so-that-fxgx-has-only-nonnegative-coe) if you have time?

Comment: Also, how to you know that $|p_{n+1}/q_{n+1} - p_n/q_n|\ge 1/D$?

Comment: You can write those fractions with denominator $D$ because $q_n\mid D$. Now minimum difference between two fractions with denominator $D$ is at-least 1/D.

Comment: Oh right the least common denominator of $q_n$ and $q_{n+1}$ divides $D$. Is $p_n/q_n$ unbounded because if for some reason it were bounded, then it would take on only finitely many values because $q_n | D$? For instance, if $p_n/q_n < R$ where $R$ is an integer, then there are at most $RD$ possibilities for $p_n/q_n$. Then there must be one of those finite values for which $Q(x) = Mk$ for infinitely many k, but that contradicts the fact that Q is a function.

Comment: Exactly, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT AND HINT FOR LARGER DEGREES.-We prove for quadratic $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c\in\mathbb Q[x]$. It is evident that the property is valid for linear polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

We have
$$\\p(r)-n=ar^2+br+c-n=0\\p(r_1)-1=ar_1^2+br_1+c-1=0\\p(r_2)-2=ar_2^2+br_2+c-2=0\\p(r_3)-3=ar_3^2+br_3+c-3=0\tag 1 $$ Taking $(1)$ as a linear system in $a,b,c$ and a new unknown $w$ one has the (very known) compatibility condition
$$\det\begin{vmatrix}r^2&r&1&n\\r_1^2&r_1&1&1\\r_2^2&r_2&1&2\\r_3^2&r_3&1&3\end{vmatrix}=0$$ from which we have $Ar^2+Br+C+nD=0$ where $A,B,C,D$ are constant. Solving the quadratic equation in $r$, the discriminant $B^2-4A(C+nD)$ should be a square so we have $$E+nF=z^2$$ whare $E$ and $F$ are constant and $n$ can be, say, integer arbitrary distinct of $1,2,3$. This is clearly absurd.